# Bootstrap 5 / SASS - Error: argument `$color-2` of `mix($color-1, $color-2, $weight: 50%)` must be a color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5

I'm getting errors in my SASS compiler with my bootstrap.scss file.

Here's the error:

```
[09:15:54] Starting 'styles'...
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_functions.scss
Error: argument `$color-2` of `mix($color-1, $color-2, $weight: 50%)` must be a color
        on line 212 of node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss, in function `mix`
        from line 212 of node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss, in function `shade-color`
        from line 994 of node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss
        from line 10 of src/scss/bootstrap.scss
>>   @return mix(black, $color, $weight);

   ----------^

[09:15:56] Finished 'styles' after 2.61 s
```

Here's the bootstrap.scss file:

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/banner";
@include bsBanner("");

// custom variables to overwrite the default one
@import "variables"; // custom vars e.g. theme-colors in here

// scss-docs-start import-stack
// Configuration
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";

// Layout & components
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
...
```

Here's my variables.scss file:

```
// // Color system

// // scss-docs-start gray-color-variables
$white:    #fff !default;
// $gray-100: #f8f9fa !default;
// $gray-200: #e9ecef !default;
...
// $gray-800: #343a40 !default;
// $gray-900: #212529 !default;
$black:    #000 !default;

...

//Grays Primary
$gray: #6f7271;
$gray-100: tint-color($gray, 90%);
$gray-200: tint-color($gray, 80%);
...

// Blues Primary
$blue-primary: #3e4765;
$blue-primary-100: tint-color($blue-primary, 90%);
...

// Blues Secondary
$blue-secondary: #00294b;
$blue-secondary-100: tint-color($blue-secondary, 90%);
$blue-secondary-200: tint-color($blue-secondary, 80%);
...

// scss-docs-start theme-color-variables
$primary:       $blue-primary;
$secondary:     $gray;
...

// scss-docs-start theme-colors-map
$theme-colors: (
  "primary":    $primary,
  "secondary":  $secondary,
  "success":    $success,
  "info":       $info,
  "warning":    $warning,
//   "danger":     $danger,
  "light":      $light,
  "dark":       $dark,
  
  // nmis brand colours
  "blue-secondary": $blue-secondary,
  "blue-secondary-900": $blue-secondary-900,
  ...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the variable `$color` is not a valid color. I can't see in your presented code where you initialized that variable. You can try if the mix works properly as you pass a valid color for the mixin, for example:

`mix(black, yellow, $weight)`

Once you are sure it works, you should be sure that the second argument (`$color-2`) of the mix is passed correctly - so make sure that the variable (`$color`) is initialized and assigned to a valid color.